# JavaScript variable: var a =(3,4,7);

Tags: javascript

```
var a =(3,4,7);
console.log(a);  // Output is 7
```

**Can you please explain how we are getting output 7?**

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator

Comment: It is clearly outputting the last value... [**Comma operator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)

Comment: What are you expecting to get?

Answer (score 9):

It's called **comma operator**. By wrapping the right hand expression in parentheses we create a group and it is evaluated each of its operands and **returns** the last value.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)

> The comma operator evaluates each of its operands (from left to right)
>   and returns the value of the last operand.

The comma operator is useful when you want to write a minifier and need to shrink the code.

For instance,

```js
print = () => console.log('add')
add_proc = (a,b) => a + b

function add(a, b){
  if(a && b){
      print();
      return add_proc(a,b)
  }
  else
  {
     return 0
  }
}

console.log(add(1,2));
```

could be minified using `comma operator` as below:

```js
print = () => console.log('add')
add_proc = (a,b) => a + b

add = (a, b)=> a && b ?(print(),add_proc(a, b)):0

console.log(add(1,2));
```

Answer (score 0):

The comma operator evaluates each of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the last operand.

Here , Seprates each Digits Ans As it is a Variable So it stores 3 then overlapped by 4 and finally 7
So final output is 7